# @predestroy needs to wait to finish the thread

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a stand-alone spring batch application, and I am trying to test the behavior of graceful shutdown by using  @PreDestroy feature. I see that the application waits for all current processes to complete once I shutdown the application. The only exception is a poller thread and it dies halfway although the @Predestroy method is being invoked in that class.
My poller thread simply implements Runnable interface. I have put a short sleep in the run method and placed a log statement before and after the sleep. While it is sleeping I have the killed the process, it never resumes the statement after the sleep statement.

Ideally, I was hoping the application will not shutdown until the thread completes it business.  Please help to to resolve this issue.

Thanks.
J

Comment: how are you killing the process? if you are doing kill -9, that would kill the jvm.

Comment: I am doing a soft kill, I can see the  PreDestroy  method is getting executed. With kill -9, it won't even go to the PreDestroy  method. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: did you solve this problem ?